# Runnable with a method parameter

Tags: java

Is it possible to have a method parameter in `Runnable` like this one:

```
public Runnable createRunnable(Method a_void_method) {
    Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            //a_void_method
        }
    };
    return runnable;
}
```

Or is there any way to do like that?

Answer (score 4):

The `Runnable` you are creating doesn't differ from any other anonymous, nested, class. Thus you can pass any 'effectively final' object reference to it. In your case the `Method` reference is just fine.

However a `Method` needs an instance or a `class` to operate on, otherwise the method doesn't know which polymorphic method to call, nor which data to pass.

If your Java version is pre-8 you need to pass the object instance to your `createRunnable`:

```
public Runnable createRunnable(Object instance, Method method) {
   return new Runnable() {
       try {
           method.invoke(instance);
            } catch (IllegalAccessException | IllegalArgumentException | InvocationTargetException e) {
                 // handle exception
                 throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
   };
)
```

In Java-8 and later you could use a lambda method reference, removing the need to create a function:

```
Runnable r = () -> { 
            try {
                method.invoke(instance);
            } catch (IllegalAccessException | IllegalArgumentException | InvocationTargetException e) {
                 // handle exception
                 throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        };
```

or, if you know the method and instance already you could just as well use

```
Runnable r = object::method;
```

Answer (score 3):

`Runnable` represents a method that takes no parameters and returns `void`. If you want to represent a method that does take parameters, consider using [`Consumer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Consumer.html) and [`BiConsumer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/BiConsumer.html).

Or maybe you are asking how to convert from a `Consumer` to a `Runnable`, try this:

```
private static <T> Runnable toRunnable(Consumer<? super T> consumer, T parameter) {
    return () -> consumer.accept(parameter);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really have a `Method` obtained by reflection,

```
 public void run() {
     a_void_method.invoke(instance_to_invoke_on);
     // or if method is static,
     // a_void_method.invoke(null);
 }
```

Otherwise, you may be looking for lambdas, and for [method references](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html) in particular:

```
class X {
    void a_method() { ... }
}

X x = ...
Runnable runnable = x::a_method;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Runnable to represent a void-returning method taking no parameters like this.

```
public Runnable createRunnable(Runnable a_void_method) {
        Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                a_void_method.run();
            }
        };
        return runnable;
}
```

or a more compact form:

```
public Runnable createRunnable(Runnable a_void_method) {
      return () -> a_void_method.run();           
}
```

or using method reference.

```
public Runnable createRunnable(Runnable a_void_method) {
       return a_void_method::run;
}
```

Further, you might not even need to wrap the logic of `a_void_method` in a method instead you can assign it directly inline:

```
Runnable runnable = ClassName::a_void_method;
```

If you want to represent a void-returning method taking parameters then look into [Consumer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/function/Consumer.html) or [BiConsumer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/function/Consumer.html) or a [specific specialization of it](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/function/package-summary.html).